# using runOnUiThread() inside thread to update User interface

Tags: android

Can I use runOnUiThread()  inside a thread to update the user interface while running the thread, or handler is more efficient ? .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use `runOnUiThread()` from a non UI thread to update the UI. That method uses a handler internally if you are not currently on the UI thread so using your own handler will not be more efficient. If you are already on the UI thread then the runnable will be executed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency isn't a big deal here. Handler might be useful if you need to call another class (for instance, if your thread runs in a class and you need to update the fragment). If you're in a fragment/activity and have access to the elements you need to update, then it may be easier to do runOnUIThread. It's all about code access really.

I personally use callbacks.